# How to search in all the files of a project in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to find all occurrences of a particular string in all the code files of a project of mine. Search/replace panels popping up on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> don't seem to offer to chose the search domain. Is there such a facility available in IntelliJ Idea?

Comment: how to search for work with regards to starts with , cause am searching for int event = 0  but it shows private int event = 0

Answer (score 518, accepted):

**Find in Path:**

Edit > Find > Find in Path

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

Documentation: [Find the search string in a project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html#find_in_project).

Comment: For those using the eclipse keymap: Ctrl-H.

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + F works also on Mac OS

Comment: for me it's `cmd` + `shift` + `F` on Mac OS

Comment: For Mac, there're 2 keymaps, `Mac OS X 10.5+` and `Mac OS X`. If you use the `10.5+` keymap, then use `command` instead of `ctrl`.

Comment: In recent versions, the name of this keybind has been changed to "Find in files"

Comment: Yes, the keyboard shortcut does depend on your keymap preference setting. Look in the "Edit>Find>Find in files" menu item to find the configured shortcut.

Answer (score 30):

To clarify, the default Keymap for **Find in Path** on Mac OS X is also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Comment: for me it's `cmd` not `ctrl`

Comment: @nburk is correct, and this answer is not (anymore?) the default.

Answer (score 13):

For mac users, find in path is: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + ⇧ + <kbd>F</kbd> (Command + Shift + F).